# merging factor variables of equal length but different levels ignoring NA

Tags: r, forcats

I have survey data from various sources. Most are factor variables with different levels. When merging, this means that there are variables of the same length, each of them contains a number of rows with information, while the other rows are `NA`. So when merging each row in the complete df should have information in it, while disregarding the `NA`'s and maintaining the same length.

I have tried the `forcats` package as it contains functions to manipulate differing factor levels, but I have not found a solutions that satisfies removing the `NA`'s while merging the different factor with their corresponding levels.

```
v1 <- as.factor(c("a","b","c","x","x",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
v2<- as.factor(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"c","c","c","b","a",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
v3<- as.factor(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"f","c","c","b","a"))
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

A merged variable should look like a factor that contains:

```
("a","b","c","x","x","c","c","c","b","a","f","c","c","b","a")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(magrittr)

lapply(df, function(x){
  x[!is.na(x)] %>%
    t %>%
    as.character
  }) %>%
  unlist %>%
  as.factor %>%
  `names<-`(NULL)

 [1] a b c x x c c c b a f c c b a
Levels: a b c f x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

map(df, ~na.omit(.x)) %>% unlist %>% unname
 [1] a b c x x c c c b a f c c b a
Levels: a b c x f
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `unlist` and then `Filter` to omit `NA` values.

```
Filter(function(x) !is.na(x) , unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))
#[1] a b c x x c c c b a f c c b a
#Levels: a b c x f
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   transmute(v = coalesce(!!! .)) %>% 
   pull(v)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "x" "x" "c" "c" "c" "b" "a" "f" "c" "c" "b" "a"
```

---

Or more compactly

```
library(purrr)
reduce(df, coalesce)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "x" "x" "c" "c" "c" "b" "a" "f" "c" "c" "b" "a"
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
do.call(pmin, c(lapply(df, as.character), na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "x" "x" "c" "c" "c" "b" "a" "f" "c" "c" "b" "a"
```